# Float value returns with double quotes from [String: AnyObject] in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, floating-point, anyobject

I have no idea why the float value always comes with double quotes when I used `[String: AnyObject]`. Do you guys have some methods so that I can get the correct result?

```
let appliedLoyalty: Float = 1.05
let appliedWallet: Float = 0.55

let payLoad: [String: AnyObject] = ["custid": custid! as AnyObject, "discounts": ["loyalty": appliedLoyalty,"wallet": appliedWallet] as AnyObject] // custid is string value

print(payLoad)
```

When I print the payLoad, the float value comes in double quotes.

```
["discounts": {
    "loyalty" = "1.05";
    "wallet" = "0.45";
}, "custid": "puma"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace AnyObject with Any like below:

```
let appliedLoyalty: Float = 1.05
let appliedWallet: Float = 0.55
let custID = "puma"
let payLoad: [String: Any] = ["custid": custID, "discounts": ["loyalty": appliedLoyalty,"wallet": appliedWallet]] // custid is string value

print(payLoad)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. It is working fine.

Comment: There's no need for the casts (`"puma" as String` and the `as Any` cast inside the dictionary), type inference will do its job, especially you're working with such simple types.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you are right.. as per you said i have updated answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `print(payLoad)` then dictionary's `description` method is called. And the implementation of `description` method does the same as printed on the console. Instead of printing the dictionary you should use `JSONSerialization` to see the actual json. Use below code or use breakpoints to check what is being stored inside `payLoad`

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payLoad, options: .prettyPrinted)
let jsonStr = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonStr!)
```